# Getting a program to read a file, and print every 10th line of the file

Tags: python, loops, file

this is my code thus far:

```
with open("exam2text.txt") as fh:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fh):
        if lineno % step == 10:
            print(line)
```

the second problem im working on is to write a function that accepts two parameters: a string 'filename' and an integer 'frequency.' Frequency will be how often to print a line- hard coded to 10 in the first part.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you want to get the input from a user, look for the in-built function called input(). And yeah, as gelonida says read up on a few tutorials.

Comment: You've got too separate questions here, and haven't showed what is not working as expected. Can you clean up your question a bit, give us an input and expected output? I think if you do this, and maybe write some pseudo-code, you may answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean:

```
def print_every_nth_line(fname, n):
    with open(fname) as fh:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fh):
        if lineno % n == 0:
            print(line)
```

I suggest to read some tutorials or documents about python and functions. This should clarify things. things like named arguments, *args, **kwargs, etc. can be quite helpful to learn.

I also fixed the line:

```
if lineno % step == 10:
```

which should have been

```
if lineno % 10 == 0:
```